# Flask-Admin refresh files list

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

The [Flask-Admin form tutorial code](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/examples/forms/app.py) creates a list from the files in a directory. This is the populating of the list:

```
def build_sample_db():
    # Populating the pdf files 
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        file = File()
        file.name = "Example " + str(i)
        file.path = "example_" + str(i) + ".pdf"
        db.session.add(file)
    db.session.commit()
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Build a sample db on the fly, if one does not exist yet.
    build_sample_db()
    # Start app
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I've changed the code for populating to this:

```
# get all files in a directory
def build_sample_db():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    # It lists the files in a directory 
    ls_output = next(os.walk('/home/bor/flask-admin/examples/forms/files/'))[2]
    for f in ls_output:
        file = File()
        file.path = f
        db.session.add(file)

    db.session.commit()
    return
```

It lists the whole directory without hard-coded values. But it refreshes only on the start of the app.

[Forms in Flask-Admin](http://examples.flask-admin.org/forms/admin/file/) is the example and how it looks.

The view is added here:

```
 admin.add_view(FileView(File, db.session))
```

Files view:

```
class FileView(sqla.ModelView):
    # Pass additional parameters to 'path' to FileUploadField constructor
    form_args = {
        'path': {
            'label': 'File',
            'base_path': file_path,
            'allow_overwrite': False
        }
    }
    # No
    def __init__():
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
        ls_output = next(os.walk('/home/bor/flask-admin/examples/forms/files/'))[2]
        for f in ls_output:
            file = File()
            file.path = f
            db.session.add(file)
        db.session.commit()
```

Where to add the code for populating, so it can be refreshed and the files in the dir taken again? Database would be recreated as well just for the example. 
I don't want to create a new view, but to refresh this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override your view's `index_view` method. Something like (untested) :

```
from flask_admin import expose

class FileView(sqla.ModelView):
    # Pass additional parameters to 'path' to FileUploadField constructor
    form_args = {
        'path': {
            'label': 'File',
            'base_path': file_path,
            'allow_overwrite': False
        }
    }

    @expose('/')
    def index_view(self):
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
        ls_output = next(os.walk('/home/bor/flask-admin/examples/forms/files/'))[2]
        for f in ls_output:
            file = File()
            file.path = f
            db.session.add(file)
        db.session.commit()
        return super(FileView, self).index_view()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Flask-Admin file example](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/examples/file/app.py) also answers the question. The files refresh, only the database is not added, but that's OK:

```
from flask_admin.contrib import fileadmin
# irrelevant code removed - see in the link 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create directory
    path = op.join(op.dirname(__file__), 'files')
    try:
        os.mkdir(path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    # Create admin interface
    admin = admin.Admin(app, 'Example: Files')
    # Another way to add view
    admin.add_view(fileadmin.FileAdmin(path, '/files/', name='Files'))

    # Start app
    app.run(debug=True)
```